# Make a link on several lines

Tags: css, hyperlink

It's not as basic as you might think. Take a look at this picture: [image: "My problem"]

Now you can see that the link is out of the content box. Normal text hopps down to the next line, but links and long words don't. Any fixes for this? The text that is placed there is placed via PHP, just saying.

Comment: Why to display whole link ? just display some words in a tag.

Comment: I guess, but can't I make it on both lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `word-break: break-all` to break up really long words like that.

You can also [truncate the string](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) with these properties:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Example of both: http://jsbin.com/uzoyag/2/edit